# inserting values using multiple actions in same controller and same jdbc template query

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

## Errors

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE rd SET LabNo=?,Category =?,ProductCode=?,StageCode=?,BatchNo=?,Analysis=?,RequestBy=?, Date1=?,ReceivedBy=?,Date2=?,RawNo=?,Test=?,Result=?,SubmittedBy=?,Date3=?, WHERE ArNo=?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ArNo='2015-06-07 00:00:00'' at line 1


type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE rd SET LabNo=?,Category =?,ProductCode=?,StageCode=?,BatchNo=?,Analysis=?,RequestBy=?, Date1=?,ReceivedBy=?,Date2=?,RawNo=?,Test=?,Result=?,SubmittedBy=?,Date3=?, WHERE ArNo=?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ArNo='2015-06-07 00:00:00'' at line 1

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE rd SET LabNo=?,Category =?,ProductCode=?,StageCode=?,BatchNo=?,Analysis=?,RequestBy=?, Date1=?,ReceivedBy=?,Date2=?,RawNo=?,Test=?,Result=?,SubmittedBy=?,Date3=?, WHERE ArNo=?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ArNo='2015-06-07 00:00:00'' at line 1
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)



root cause 
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE rd SET LabNo=?,Category =?,ProductCode=?,StageCode=?,BatchNo=?,Analysis=?,RequestBy=?, Date1=?,ReceivedBy=?,Date2=?,RawNo=?,Test=?,Result=?,SubmittedBy=?,Date3=?, WHERE ArNo=?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ArNo='2015-06-07 00:00:00'' at line 1
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:233)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:603)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:868)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:876)
    com.elakk.dao.EmployeDaoImpl.saveorupdate(EmployeDaoImpl.java:128)
    com.elakk.service.EmployeServiceImpl.saveorupdate(EmployeServiceImpl.java:32)
    com.elakk.controller.EmployeeController.registerprocess(EmployeeController.java:53)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

### Code

```
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "rd", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showrdPage(HttpSession session) {
        session.setAttribute("RD", "rd");
        System.out.println("invoking rd page");
        return "rd";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "rdProcess", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerprocess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            @ModelAttribute("rd") RD rd) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String operation = request.getParameter("rd.getOperation");
        System.out.println("bname......................" + rd.getOperation());
        System.out.println("test............");
        if (rd.getOperation() == "save") {
            rd.setStatus("RDSave");
        } else if (rd.getOperation() == "update") {
            rd.setStatus("RDSubmit");
        }


            System.out.println("Test registerProcess");
            rd = employeeService.saveorupdate(rd);

        return "rd";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct this code

```
Date3=?, WHERE
```

there should not be a comma here

Comment: when am  compiling this code just inserting into database, i want to update same data in database.

Comment: Yes... It is throwing an exception due to the error that I fix in my answer

Comment: so read the next error and fix that *Unable to convert value "wer" from type 'java.lang.String' to type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "wer"]* - please also accept my answer

Comment: @Override
public boolean isValidARNumber(String arNumber){
 boolean arNotExist = false;
 
 Object[] loginObj = new Object[]{arNumber};
   int listData = 0;
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) from RD where ARNO = ?";
        if(jdbcTemplate != null){
         listData = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql, loginObj);
        }       
        
        if(listData != 0){
         arNotExist = true;
        }
     
 return arNotExist;
 
}           please help to update this in above controller method